# Tables not created, Using Entities from maven jar dependency in multiple applications in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Having Two Projects

1. my-app
2. my-entities

I have my entities in my-entities and i uploading this repository to bitbucket fro hosting then using same repository in my  "my-app" project which is a spring boot application and containing database configs like username, dbname, password and i am using spring data jpa with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Sample Entity class present in my-enties

```
@Entity
public class OrganisationDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrganisationDetails{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

But tables are not created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` - is used to update the current schema

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` - is used to create new schema

Normally in development phases the combination - `create-drop` is used

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

You can read more on how to initialize database with spring-boot and JPA [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate).

Another vital thing is to specify your SQL dialect. For example for MySql5

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```